# How to get files with a filename starting with a certain letter?

Tags: java

I wrote some code to read a text file from C drive directly given a path.

```
String fileName1 = "c:\\M2011001582.TXT";
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName1));
```

I want to get a list of files whose filename starts with M. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add a check fileName1.startsWith("M") .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> "but how can i write a code that file is exist in local drive or not"

To scan a directory for files matching a condition:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class DirScan
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File root = new File("C:\\");
        FilenameFilter beginswithm = new FilenameFilter()
        {
         public boolean accept(File directory, String filename) {
              return filename.startsWith("M");
          }
        };

        File[] files = root.listFiles(beginswithm);
        for (File f: files)
        {
            System.out.println(f);
        }
    }
}
```

(The files will exist, otherwise they wouldn't be found).

Comment: internal error; cannot instantiate () at <anonymous FileListFilter> to ()

Comment: I don't get that error - but there were a couple of typos that preventing the example code compiling. I have fixed these and added surrounding code so it's a complete runnable example.

Comment: Try reading the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/File.html - see the getName() method.

Comment: i have to display that files content after clicking on each file...so i written a code for displaying file...but i am confusing how to link this...because i written code as`while ((fileData = is.readLine()) != null) {
                        Sno = lineCount++;
                        batchno = fileData.substring(0, 6);....`

Comment: I think you need to start a new question for that - comments don't work very well for detailed code discussions...

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string based on the token '\' and take the second element in the array and check it by using the startsWith() method avaialble on the String object

```
String splitString = fileName1.split("\\") ;
//check if splitString is not null and size is greater than 1 and then do the following

if(splitString[1].startsWith("M")){
// do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: but how can i write a code that file is exist in local drive or not and how to display it

Answer (score 0):

To check if file exist, you can check in [File Class docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)
In Nutshell:

```
File f = new File(fileName1);
if(f.exists()) {
    //do something                  
}
```